# Invalid KeyConditionExpression in boto3 dynamodb query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

This is how my table looks like:

> [image]

`toHash` is my primary partition key and `timestamp` is the sort key.

So, when I am executing this code [For getting the reverse sorted list of `timestamp`]:

import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
response = client.query(
    TableName='logs',
    Limit=1,
    ScanIndexForward=False,
    KeyConditionExpression="toHash = :X",
)
```

I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined; attribute value: :X
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  **Why isn't `X` considered a valid attribute value?**

Comment: You need to provide an ``ExpressionAttributeValues`` clause to the query to supply the value for ``:X`` in the query.

Answer (score 4):

Add `ExpressionAttributeValues` as mentioned below:-

```
response = client.query(
    TableName='logs',
    Limit=1,
    ScanIndexForward=False,
    KeyConditionExpression="toHash = :X",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={":X" : {"S" : "somevalue"}}
)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is why I don't use boto directly anymore. The API for what should be simple stuff like this is nuts. @notionquest is correct, you need to add the `ExpressionAttributeValues`. I don't mess with these things anymore. I use [dynamof](https://github.com/rayepps/dynamof). Heres an example with your query:

```py
from boto3 import client
from dynamof import db as make_db
from dynamof import query

client = client('dynamodb', endpoint_url='http://localstack:4569')
db = make_db(client)

db(query(
    table_name='logs',
    conditions=attr('toHash').equals('somevalue')
))
```

`dynamof` build the `KeyConditionExpression` and `ExpressionAttributeValues` for you.

*disclaimer: I wrote dynamof*